# Can ground and voltage terminals be connected by a wire?

Tags: circuit-analysis, nmos

Helo, I am working on an assignment for a circuit analysis class. I have always been a bit fuzzy about the following: Can I assume that the two top terminals are the same node, the two ground terminals are the same node, and effectively connect them by a wire? Or should analysis be done without this assumption?

[image: NMOS 2PN]

Thanks!

Comment: Yes and no.  Effectively they are at the same potential,  so you can connect a wire between them.  But their analysis is separate,  so there is no need to do.   In fact, base and collector can be at different potentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can ground and voltage terminals be connected by a wire?

Yes. Ground terminals con be connected by wire. V<sub>DD</sub> terminals can be connected by wire.

Using this drawing format can eliminates a lot of clutter from a schematic and gives instant visualisation of the voltage at those points without having to trace back to the power supply.

Comment: So the current is flowing upwards along the left side of the NMOS, then back down the left and so on? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: conventional current flows down on both sides.  The drawing implies that there is a 10 Volt battery with its positive terminal connected to Vdd, and negative terminal to Ground/

Comment: For circuit analysis you can draw a line across the top and bottom and then draw your current loops inside each of the resultant rectangles. It would be usual to draw these all clockwise or anti- clockwise.